# Restrict who can create Pull Requests in repo on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to restrict what users are allowed to create Pull Requests within a specific repo on GitHub?

Comment: Yes.  Please check GitHub's official documentation: https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/

Comment: ...which indicate that no, you can't restrict that unless you make your repository private. Anyone with read access to your repository can submit pull requests.